# Javascript CreateElement button

Tags: javascript, button, createelement

I have a problem I been suffering on for a couple hours now.
The context is, I need to make a button with action listener in JavaScript and add it into a table.

Here is the code I have

```
var _button = document.createElement("button");
_button.data = _a;
_button.innerHTML = 'click me';
_button.onclick = function()
{
    alert("hello, world");
}

var table = document.getElementById("tableOnline");
var row = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

var _weakbutton = _button.outerHTML;
_weakbutton.onclick = function()
{
    alert("hello, world");
}

cell1.innerHTML = "h";
cell2.innerHTML = "o";
cell3.innerHTML = _weakbutton;
```

The code works if I add the create the button and add it onto the body (without weakButton), but how can I make it work into a table?

Kind regards,
Zhendos.

EDIT:
Because requested, here is the table we talk about.

```
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "table">
  <thead id = "thead">
   <tr>
    <th> firstname <th>
    <th> lastname </th>
    <th> organisation </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant ([mcve]) HTML as well.

Comment: FYI: `_weakbutton.onclick`, doesn't set a click handler since `_weakbutton` is just a `string` variable.

Comment: If I add the onclick onto the button and make a weakButton, the onclick event is gone.

Comment: Also `table.insertRow(1);` will only work if there is already row(s) inside the table, [the optional argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow#Syntax) is the index where you want the new row. The argument cannot be greater than the number of currently existing rows. Check your console for errors

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var _weakbutton = _button.outerHTML;` create a copy of the button with `var _weakbutton = _button.cloneNode(true);`. This will create a new button, based on your original one.

Because this is now a button node, you can't add it with `cell3.innerHTML = _weakbutton;` but have to use `cell3.appendChild( _weakbutton );`

So, with your code it would be

```js
var _button = document.createElement("button");
_button.data = "hi";
_button.innerHTML = 'click me';
_button.onclick = function()
{
    alert("hello, world");
}

var table = document.getElementById("tableOnline");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

var _weakbutton = _button.cloneNode(true)
_weakbutton.onclick = function()
{
    alert("hello, world");
}

cell1.innerHTML = "h";
cell2.innerHTML = "o";
cell3.appendChild( _weakbutton );
```

```html
<table id="tableOnline"></table>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Zhendos glad to help please consider accepting this answer if it helped :)